# using time_synchronizer to combine the force and position data from different sensor

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I try to use the time_synchronizer to get the force and position data from a force sensor and NDI, the code is show here which imitated from #q297174:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/time_synchronizer.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>
#include <tf2/LinearMath/Quaternion.h>
#include <tf2_ros/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Wrench.h>       
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseArray.h>  
#include "std_msgs/Float64.h"

void callback(const geometry_msgs::WrenchConstPtr& netft_data, const geometry_msgs::PoseArrayConstPtr& targets) 
{

  static tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster tf2_broadcaster;

  geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transformStamped;

  transformStamped.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
  transformStamped.header.frame_id = "ts_frame";
  transformStamped.child_frame_id = "prism_frame";
  transformStamped.transform.translation.x = targets->poses[0].position.x;
  transformStamped.transform.translation.y = targets->poses[0].position.y;
  transformStamped.transform.translation.z = targets->poses[0].position.z;
  tf2::Quaternion q;
  transformStamped.transform.rotation.x = netft_data->force.x;
  transformStamped.transform.rotation.y = netft_data->force.y;
  transformStamped.transform.rotation.z = netft_data->force.z;

  transformStamped.transform.rotation.w = targets->poses[0].orientation.w;

  tf2_broadcaster.sendTransform(transformStamped);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "get_all_sensor_in_one");

  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Wrench> force_sub(nh, "/netft_data", 1);   
  message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseArray> pose_sub(nh, "/targets", 1);     
  message_filters::TimeSynchronizer<geometry_msgs::Wrench, geometry_msgs::PoseArray> sync(force_sub, pose_sub, 10);      
  sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2));       


  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

what i do is just change the topic and the type of argument, but it is wrong somewhere. I'm pretty new of this, so can you help me??

error:

```
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/time_synchronizer.h:39:0,
                 from /home/edward/kuka_catkin/src/iiwa_stack-master-Sunrise1.9/iiwa_ros/src/topic_synchronizer/get_all_sensor_in_one.cpp:8:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/sync_policies/exact_time.h: In instantiation of ‘void message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::add(const typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::Events, i>::type&) [with int i = 0; M0 = geometry_msgs::Wrench_<std::allocator<void> >; M1 = geometry_msgs::PoseArray_<std::allocator<void> >; M2 = message_filters::NullType; M3 = message_filters::NullType; M4 = message_filters::NullType; M5 = message_filters::NullType; M6 = message_filters::NullType; M7 = message_filters::NullType; M8 = message_filters::NullType; typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::Events, i>::type = ros::MessageEvent<const geometry_msgs::Wrench_<std::allocator<void> > >]’:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:358:5:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::cb(const typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename Policy::Events, i>::type&) [with int i = 0; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<geometry_msgs::Wrench_<std::allocator<void> >, geometry_msgs::PoseArray_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>; typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename Policy::Events, i>::type = ros::MessageEvent<const geometry_msgs::Wrench_<std::allocator<void> > >]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:290:138:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&, F6&, F7&, F8&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Wrench_<std::allocator<void> > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseArray_<std::allocator<void> > >; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F6 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F7 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F8 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<geometry_msgs::Wrench_<std::allocator<void> >, geometry_msgs::PoseArray_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:282:52:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&, F6&, F7&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Wrench_<std::allocator<void> > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseArray_<std::allocator<void> > >; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F6 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F7 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<geometry_msgs::Wrench_<std::allocator<void> >, geometry_msgs::PoseArray_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:275:48:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&, F6&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Wrench_<std::allocator<void> > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseArray_<std::allocator<void> > >; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F6 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<geometry_msgs::Wrench_<std::allocator<void> >, geometry_msgs::PoseArray_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:268:44:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Wrench_<std::allocator<void> > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseArray_<std::allocator<void> > >; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<geometry_msgs::Wrench_<std::allocator<void> >, geometry_msgs::PoseArray_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:261:40:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Wrench_<std::allocator<void> > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseArray_<std::allocator<void> > >; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<geometry_msgs::Wrench_<std::allocator<void> >, geometry_msgs::PoseArray_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:254:36:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Wrench_<std::allocator<void> > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseArray_<std::allocator<void> > >; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<geometry_msgs::Wrench_<std::allocator<void> >, geometry_msgs::PoseArray_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:247:32:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Wrench_<std::allocator<void> > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseArray_<std::allocator<void> > >; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<geometry_msgs::Wrench_<std::allocator<void> >, geometry_msgs::PoseArray_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:240:28:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Wrench_<std::allocator<void> > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseArray_<std::allocator<void> > >; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<geometry_msgs::Wrench_<std::allocator<void> >, geometry_msgs::PoseArray_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/time_synchronizer.h:120:24:   required from ‘message_filters::TimeSynchronizer<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::TimeSynchronizer(F0&, F1&, uint32_t) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Wrench_<std::allocator<void> > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseArray_<std::allocator<void> > >; M0 = geometry_msgs::Wrench_<std::allocator<void> >; M1 = geometry_msgs::PoseArray_<std::allocator<void> >; M2 = message_filters::NullType; M3 = message_filters::NullType; M4 = message_filters::NullType; M5 = message_filters::NullType; M6 = message_filters::NullType; M7 = message_filters::NullType; M8 = message_filters::NullType; uint32_t = unsigned int]’
/home/edward/kuka_catkin/src/iiwa_stack-master-Sunrise1.9/iiwa_ros/src/topic_synchronizer/get_all_sensor_in_one.cpp:49:114:   required from here
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/sync_policies/exact_time.h:127:101: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘ros::message_traits::TimeStamp<geometry_msgs::Wrench_<std::allocator<void> >, void>’
     Tuple& t = tuples_[mt::TimeStamp<typename mpl::at_c<Messages, i>::type>::value(*evt.getMessage())];
                                                                                                     ^
make[2]: *** [iiwa_stack-master-Sunrise1.9/iiwa_ros/CMakeFiles/get_all_sensor_in_one.dir/src/topic_synchronizer/get_all_sensor_in_one.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [iiwa_stack-master-Sunrise1.9/iiwa_ros/CMakeFiles/get_all_sensor_in_one.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311531/using-time_synchronizer-to-combine-the-force-and-position-data-from-different-sensor/) by [RLoad](https://answers.ros.org/users/38655/rload/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-12-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> /opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/sync_policies/exact_time.h:127:101: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘ros::message_traits::TimeStamp<geometry_msgs::Wrench_<std::allocator<void> >, void>’
> ```

```
     Tuple& t = tuples_[mt::TimeStamp<typename mpl::at_c<Messages, i>::type>::value(*evt.getMessage())];
```

`Wrench` messaged do not include a `Header` field ([docs](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Wrench.html)). Without a header, there is no timestamp information available with which the `TimeSynchronizer` can synchronise incoming messages. From the [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Time_Synchronizer):

> The `TimeSynchronizer` filter synchronizes incoming channels by the timestamps contained in their headers [..]

You'll need to use a message with a `Header`, such as [geometry_msgs/WrenchStamped](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/WrenchStamped.html).

> what i do is just change the topic and the type of argument, but it is wrong somewhere

that is a good approach, but as most things are (almost statically) typed with topics (at least in C++), can lead to issues such as the one you encountered.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RLoad](https://answers.ros.org/users/38655/rload/) on 2018-12-27**:
Thanks a lot! It works!
While I still have some question just like you mention. Now I put the data of position and force which have same timestamp into one message with type of TransformStamped, while the force is put into the rotation of TransformStamped.

**Comment by [RLoad](https://answers.ros.org/users/38655/rload/) on 2018-12-27**:
Sure this will make some trouble in future, so what should I do to save all this data from sensors (position,orientation,force,torque) to a message or a topic which is convenience to record or used in future? Thanks you!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-28**:
`PoseArray` already has a `Header`, so no need to change that. `Wrench` has a variant with a `Header` called `WrenchStamped`.

Don't use `TransformStamped`, it's not meant for this type of application.

**Comment by [RLoad](https://answers.ros.org/users/38655/rload/) on 2019-01-01**:
Thank you and Happy New Year, I already change the Wrench to the WrenchStamped, it works well. Can you recommend a better way to do this work? I'm not so familiar with this. Thanks again.